# Protractor tests inconsistently passing / failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, automated-tests, protractor

The problem that I have with this test is that sometimes it passes, sometimes it fails, and when it does the latter a "Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .add.create_ServiceOrders)" message appears in the console. Idk what to do to fix it :(

```
 describe('angularjs homepage', function() {

   it('should greet the named user', function() {     
  //browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
  browser.get('https://int.m-tech.com/hotsosmobile/app/Index?/login#/login');
  browser.waitForAngular();

  var input = element(by.model('loginInfo.login'));
  input.sendKeys('xxx');
  expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe('xxx');

  var input = element(by.model('loginInfo.password'));
  input.sendKeys('yyy');
  expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe('yyy');

  browser.waitForAngular(); 

  browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();

  browser.waitForAngular(); 

  var AddButton = element(by.css(".add.create_ServiceOrders" ));
  browser.actions().mouseDown(AddButton).mouseUp().perform();   
  browser.actions().mouseMove(AddButton).click().perform();

  browser.waitForAngular(); 

  var AddButton = element(by.css(".icon-standard-issue-floors" ));
  browser.actions().mouseDown(AddButton).mouseUp().perform();  
  browser.actions().mouseMove(AddButton).click().perform();

  browser.waitForAngular(); 
  .....
 });
});
```

Comment: Hey guys, so I followed ji-ruh's advice and now I get "Failed: element not visible" why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Base on my experience, I usually do separate it in another `it` function something like this.

```
var AddButton = element(by.css(".add.create_ServiceOrders" ));

it ( 'should pass', function () {
browser.actions().mouseDown(AddButton).mouseUp().perform();   
});

it ( 'should pass', function () {
browser.actions().mouseMove(AddButton).click().perform();
});
```

Comment: Cool! thanks, now I don't get the "Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .add.create_ServiceOrders)" message anymore, now I get the "Failed: element not visible" one :/

Comment: This is actually bad solution. Jasmine is designed that your 'it' is a testcase, and describe is a test suite. With this aproach you are losing all benefits of beforeAll, beforeEach, afterAll, afterEach, and getting a lot of pain with reporting results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for element to be ready, before manipulating. Try this:

```
var AddButton = $(".add.create_ServiceOrders");
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(AddButton), 5000, 'Button should be visible');
browser.actions().mouseDown(AddButton).mouseUp().perform();
browser.actions().mouseMove(AddButton).click().perform();
...
```